# Cannot save DateTime from EF "Code First" to MySQL Remote Database

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework

**Introduction**

I've a MySQL Table like this:

```
id - primary key
name - string
surname - string
created_at - DateTime default 0000-00-00 00:00:00
updated_at - Datetime default 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Which is a remote table that I've accesso to. I'm creating a local WPF Desktop application using EF 6. The application works fine, it does everything from connection to basic CRUD operations with only a little detail that's driving my crazy.

First here's the Entity bounded to the table.

```
[Table("users")]
public class User : Entity
{
    #region Table Columns
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _surname;
    private DateTime _createdAt;
    private DateTime _updatedAt;
    #endregion

    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId
    {
        get { return this._id; }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    [Column("name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set
        {
            this._name= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    [Column("surname")]
    [Required]
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return this._surname; }
        set
        {
            this._surname= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    [Column("created_at")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DataBaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt
    {
        get { return this._createdAt; }
        set
        {
            this._createdAt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt
    {
        get { return this._updatedAt; }
        set
        {
            this._updatedAt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public User()
    {
        this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        this.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Don't worry for the Abstract class *Entity*, because it has only the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

The DBContext is pretty straight forward, it has the DBSet for the Entity, nothing more nothing less.

**Problem**

Well the problem is simple, the date are not saved. For example when I create a new User and save it the date will be the default one even if I have the constructor that clearly set the date to a valid DateTime.

For example this code here:

```
User user = new User(); // Create a new User
user.Name = "Foo";
user.Surname = "Bar";
App.RemoteContext.Users.Add(user);
App.RemoteContext.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
App.RemoteContext.SaveChanges();
```

It will create a user on the remote Database with all the correct data **except** for created_at and updated_at which will be set to *0000-00-00 00:00:00 (default)*

How could I solve this issue?

**NOTE** I can't change the Remote Database type nor the Default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FML

The problem was related to `[DatabaseGenerated(DataBaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` which should be removed if you plan to handle the dates by yourself...